# System of differential equations for motion under constant-magnitude force perpendicular to velocity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, physics, classical-mechanics

It is "intuitively" known and even taught in school that if a force with constant magnitude is applied perpendicular to a body's velocily, its trajectory will be circular. Let's explore this.

From Newton's 2-nd law: $\overrightarrow{F} = m \overrightarrow{a}$, so $ \Vert\overrightarrow{F}\Vert = const \implies \Vert\overrightarrow{a}\Vert = const$. Thus, if $\overrightarrow{v} = (v_x, v_y)$ then $(v_x')^2+(v_y')^2 = const \implies v_x'v_x''+v_y'v_y'' = 0 
\ \ \ (1)$

Since $\overrightarrow{F} \perp \overrightarrow{v}$, $\ \ \ \ \overrightarrow{v} \cdot \overrightarrow{a} = (v_x, v_y) \cdot (v_x', v_y') = v_xv_x'+ v_yv_y' = 0 \ \ (2)$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$:

$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
v_x'v_x''+v_y'v_y'' = 0 \\ 
v_xv_x'+ v_yv_y' = 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$

I don't really know how to solve this system. Maybe there's even some well-known method for that? I'm interested in rigorous solution with all the details why it's unique, not just "This function works."

Comment: @Cathedral no, i said acceleration's magnitude is constant, not speed

Comment: Note that your assumption that a force of constant magnitude perpendicular to the velocity of a body **does not** imply a circular trajectory. The reason for that is that there is no single perpendicular direction to the velocity vector, there is a plane. So in the 3D space, say the initial velocity is in the $xy$ plane, and the force is also always in the $xy$ plane. Then the trajectory is circular. But if you get the force at some point to have a $z$ component, then the trajectory will not be confined in the plane any more

Comment: @Andrei i assumed planar motion

Comment: A couple of remarks: (1) I'm not sure that differentiating $(v_x')^2+(v_y')^2 = const$ is a good idea, since it introduces a higher order derivative. (2) In physical situations where such circular motion occurs, the force is often directed towards the origin (think of a fixed planet at the origin with an object orbiting it due to gravitational force), not necessarily perpendicular to the motion. This gives a different equation.

Comment: (3) Although such situations admit circular motion, there are also non-circular solutions. The initial position/velocity have to be just right for circular motion. If the object starts off with zero velocity, it will just move towards the origin in a straight line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with:
$$v_xv^{'}_x + v_yv^{'}_y=0$$
This implies:
$$v^{2}_x + v^{2}_y=R^2$$ for some constant $R$.

therfore it makes sense to parametrize as
$$v_x = R\sin(\theta(t));v_y = R\cos(\theta(t))$$ and
$$v^{'}_{x}=R\cos(\theta)\theta^{'};v^{'}_{y}=-R\sin(\theta)\theta^{'}$$

using
$(v_x')^2+(v_y')^2 = const$ we obtain

$R^2(\theta^{'}(t))^2 = const$,

so $\theta(t)=\omega t +\theta_0$, and set $\theta_0=0$ w.l.g.

Now from $v_x(t)=R\sin(\omega t)$ we conclude that

$\{x,y\}=\{x_0,y_0\} + {R \over \omega} \{\cos(\omega t),-\sin(\omega t)\}$

Comment: What's the reasoning behind $v_x = R\sin(\theta(t));v_y = R\cos(\theta(t))$$ and
$$v^{'}_{x}=R\cos(\theta)\theta^{'};v^{'}_{y}=-R\sin(\theta)\theta^{'}$? Why only functions of this form work? That's what I wanted to find out

Comment: Since $v^{2}_x+v^{2}_y = R^2$ , $v_{x},v_{y}$ are on a circle, hence every position can be parametrized by the angle. The only question now is how does the angle behave with time. As I have shown it behaves linearly, so that we can make one more integration to achieve $x,y$

Comment: I mean every *velocity* can be parametrized by an angle.